# How to Remove the addPreSearch Filter

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to remove the PreSearch filer and my code is as below. How can I achieve the same?

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("productid").removePreSearch(function () {
    Object
});

Xrm.Page.getControl("productid").addPreSearch(function () {
    fetchxml2();
});

function fetchxml2() {
    var fetchXml1 = "<filter type='and'>"
    fetchXml1 += "<condition attribute='productid' operator='in' >";
    for (var i = 0; i < Itemid.length; i++) {
        fetchXml1 += "<value>" + Itemid[i] + "</value>";
    }

    fetchXml1 += "</condition>";
    fetchXml1 += "</filter>";
    Xrm.Page.getControl("productid").addCustomFilter(fetchXml1);
    //Xrm.Page.getControl("productid").removePreSearch(fetchXml1);

};
```

Answer (score 9):

In order to be able to remove the handler via `removePreSearch`, avoid using an anonymous function by creating a named function and using that in both `addPreSearch` and `removePreSearch`:

```
function preSearchHandler(){
    fetchxml2();
}

Xrm.Page.getControl("productid").removePreSearch(preSearchHandler);

Xrm.Page.getControl("productid").addPreSearch(preSearchHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add this to the discussion:

If you, say, have three different custom filters on a lookup field, the functionality will stack when you apply a new filter.

For example, if you have an option set that calls addPreSearch() on the field, if you select all three different options, you will have all three filters applied to the field simultaneously.

say the option set has three options of [option A, option B, option C],

the corresponding functions are, for simplicity [filterA, filterB, filterC],

on the change event of the option set, for each filter that you apply, simply remove the other two (in this case).

```
if (optionSet == 810500000) {//option A

Xrm.Page.getControl('lookup').addPreSearch(filterA);
Xrm.Page.getControl('lookup').removePreSearch(filterB);
Xrm.Page.getControl('lookup').removePreSearch(filterC);
}
else if (optionSet == 810500001) {//option B

Xrm.Page.getControl('lookup').addPreSearch(filterB);
Xrm.Page.getControl('lookup').removePreSearch(filterA);
Xrm.Page.getControl('lookup').removePreSearch(filterC);
}//so on and so forth
```

I hope this helps someone out, I was able to apply custom filters to a lookup based on four distinct selections and remove the "stackable" filters by addition and removal in this manner.  It's a little ugly, but, hey, it works.  At the end of the day, sometimes the most elegant solution is to just win, win win win win.

If you need more context (fetchXml) and such, I can post that, too...but it doesn't really go along with the point I was trying to make.  These filters can be applied simultaneously!  That's the main idea I wanted to convey here.

Comment: Hey - how do I pass arguments to filterA, filterB or filterC. I need to pass the formContext & other arguments. Thanks!